# Как определить расстояние от точки до дуги между двух точек на сфере?

Tags: математика, геометрия

Есть точки А и Б на сфере, заданные широтой и долготой. Есть точка С, не лежащая на дуге АБ. Как определить расстояние от точки С до дуги?

Если перпендикулярную дугу из точки С до дуги АБ провести нельзя, то расстоянием от точки до дуги будет расстояние от С до ближайшей точки.

UPD от кэпа:

Точки лежат на сфере. Координаты угловые. Точка С тоже на сфере. Координаты точки С тоже угловые. Расстояние дуговое (по умолчанию на сфере прямых не бывает, если не указать этого в условии, так что расстоянием считается длина дуги).

---

**Что делать в случае, если А и Б антиподы я не знаю**. Но я должен знать, что они антиподы. Если не сложно, предложите проверку с погрешностью. Что значит "с погрешностью":

предположим есть точка с координатами (0;0). Ее антиподом будет 0;180 (или 0;-180). Но мне не нужен точный антипод, мне нужен антипод с небольшим отклонением. То есть с определенным радиусом вокруг точки (0;180). К примеру в 1 градус. Заменим 1 на Х, чтобы я мог вместо него подставить другое число и оно не терялось в формуле. То есть точку (0,5;179,5) я тоже буду расценивать как антипод для (0;0).

Comment: На кой черт вам тэги "gps" и "геолокация" - если задача чисто геометрическая?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ответил в UPD. Если я не прав, объясните, уберу лишние теги. я хочу как можно скорее получить ответ на вопрос, поэтому привлекаю компетентных людей.

Comment: @iRumba, а вы наведите курсор мыши на геолокацию и прочитайте описание :Р

Comment: @Visman, навел, почитал. Разве "определение местоположения" не может быть связано с вычислением?

Comment: @iRumba, в данном случае, не может. Вы забыли прочитать последние два слова.

Comment: *"Абстрактные математики с этим могут не справиться"* - тогда это будут не математики, а идиоты. Задача из школьного курса стереометрии.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, родится сын - отправлю учиться в такую школу )  Нас вот этому не учили. Даже предмета не было (  Я даже не знаю как мне найти ответ на это в гугле. А что касается абстрактных математиков, то они много чего знают, но не всегда знают для чего им эти знания. Сталкивался с такими.

Comment: Такие "абстрактные математики" не будут сидеть на SO и отвечать на вопросы.

Comment: Да, добавьте еще тэги "matlab" (матлаберы лучше знают математику, чем остальные - они точно справятся), "linux" (красноглазики вообще умнее всех) и "3d" (эти люди каждый день сферу и плоскость пересекают)

Comment: Если кто не понял, это была шутка. Не надо включать лишние тэги - вы таким образом лишь привлечете людей, которые **не** знают геометрию. Геометрию при работе с gps знать не обязательно. А кто работает с gps и знает геометрию - тот подписан на оба тэга.

Comment: *PS хотел написать решение - но пока спорил про тэги, перерыв закончился...*

Comment: @PavelMayorov, лучше бы вам на споры о тегах времени не хватило )  Ладно, будем надеяться, что здесь есть кроме вас и другие математики не идиоты, которые запросто ответят на этот вопрос. А я уже перерыл пол интернета. Осталась всего половина и вопрос будет найден сам собой ) Убрал лишние теги

Comment: Опять 25... Точки заданны как (в какой системе)??? Лежит ли точка C на сфере? что значит расстояние? расстояние - прямая или дуга по сфере? Давайте учится писать задания правильно! А то получиться как в предыдущих Ваших постах, сказка про белого бычка...

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, ответил на ваши вопросы

Comment: Да и вообще про GPS не было ни слова - Вам бы, может, на math.hashcode.ru спросить - думаю, что математики (есть там зверь, ник falcao - он, по-моему, вообще на все отвечает) подскажут наверняка, причем самое элегантное решение.